# Prerendering d3 and key functions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, webpack, prerender

I'm using webpack's prerender-spa-plugin to prerender `d3` code. When I serve the prerendered html to the client using the same javascript code there's one place where I'm rebinding new data using a key function, like so:

```
svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(data, d => d.name) // TypeError: cannot read property name of undefined
    .call(myPlot);
```

I believe this happens because the prerendering step does not save bound data to the html DOM elements, so the rebinding on the first join cannot access the `name` field because the selection has no bound data.

What's a good workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for now, but I'll wait a few days before accepting my own answer in case anyone has a better solution.

My solution has two parts:

1. Handle `undefined` in the data join key function so that data can be bound to the prerendered DOM elements by falling back to an index-join.
2. If using transitions, make sure entering elements are initialized at their final positions so that they don't animate from a default (usually 0) value. This makes sure the served pre-rendered HTML is correct.

So here's the code:

```
svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(data, d => d ? d.name : undefined) // fall back to an index join given a prerendered DOM without bound data
    .join(enter => enter.append("g").call(myPlot)) // entering elements don't transition
    .transition()
        .call(myPlot);
```

Comment: How is `data` being retrieved in your JS code? If you're using something like `import * as data from './data.json'`, then Webpack should embed `data` into your JS code and make it available during runtime.

Comment: I'm doing fetches currently, but I'm considering switching to imports so that the assets are managed by webpack instead of manually.